# How to find all JMX ports on a server?

Tags: java, jvm, port, jmx

I have an application running on 4 different servers in various containers(JVMs). All JVMs have jmx ports open. While starting the JVM, jmx ports are not defined so the port numbers are assigned by JVM automatically. Is there any way to find out the list of jmx ports on a machine ?

Answer (score 0):

System.getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port") returns the port number, would you be able to run this on all of your 4 servers? this will fetch the port number if JMX port is enabled or null if there is no port assigned to it.